# Move Virtual PC VM to another machine

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

I need to move a virtual machine that was created with Windows Virtual PC to another machine. I just copied the files in the Virtual Machines folder to another PC, but when I tried to run it, I got this message:

> 'Windows XP mode' could not be restored because of either host
>   processor type mismatch or lack of hardware-assisted virtualization
>   support in the system

Is it possible copy a virtual machine? What is correct way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way should be **cloning** the virtual machine.

As far as you problem is concerned, have you by chance hibernated the VM last time? If so, try deleting the *.vsv* file and try again.